# Show More - Show Less shows 31 row instead of 30

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html table that contains 370 rows and I also have a 'Show More - Show Less' button that by default shows only first 30 rows. It worked perfect until I added a search function.

I took it from w3schools and it works great. I've added some functionality so when somebody types something my 'shower' button disappears. And when the input is clean it appears again.

The problem is when I type something and remove it, it shows 31 row + my button, instead of 30 rows. Moreover, it shows first 30 rows +  the last one.

Show More / Show Less:

```
$('.auto-collapse').find('tr:gt(30)').hide();

  $("#shower").on("click", function () {
      if ($("#shower").html() == "Show More") {
          $("#shower").attr("class", "btn btn-block btn-info");
          $("#shower").html("Show Less");
      } else {
          $("#shower").attr("class", "btn btn-block btn-primary");
          $("#shower").html("Show More");
      }
      $('.auto-collapse').find('tr:gt(30)').toggle();
  });
```

Search Function:

```
function searchFunction() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td1, td2, i;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("pairs");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
          td1 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
          td2 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
          if (input.value.length > 0) {
            $("#shower").css("display", "none");
          } else {
            $('.auto-collapse').find('tr:gt(30)').hide();
            $("#shower").css("display", "block");
          }
          if (td1 || td2) {
            if (td1.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || td2.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
              tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

What might cause the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your search function's logic:

- loop over each `tr`
- when no value for `#myInput`, hide all `tr` after the 30th
- check whether the value of `#myInput` is found among the current `tr`'s `td`s (and an empty string is found in any string!)
- conclusion: the last item is set to be visible *after* it has been hidden as a `tr` above the 30th, and you're doing stuff inside the loop that could be done only once out of the loop (and all the previous items were hidden by the *next* iteration of the loop!)

Your search function should be more like this:

```
function searchFunction() {
  // first, check if we have an input: if not, just reset the list
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  if (!input.value.length) {
    $('.auto-collapse').find('tr').show(); // force all to show
    $('.auto-collapse').find('tr:gt(30)').hide(); // then hide what we want
    // don't forget to reset #shower's text to 'Show More'
    // (should be in another function and shared between here and #shower.onClick)
    $("#shower").html("Show More");
    $("#shower").css("display", "block");
    return; // stop right here, we don't want to execute a search (input is empty)
  }
  // now only in case of a search, we disable #shower and we select which line to show
  $("#shower").css("display", "none");
  var filter, table, tr, td1, td2, i;
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("pairs");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td1 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    td2 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    if (td1 || td2) {
      if (td1.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || td2.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `toggle`, not `hide` or `show`. The search function also changes the visibility of rows. When you then toggle all the rows after 30, the rows that were matched by search will be hidden, and the rows that were not matched will be shown, because you're toggling each of them.

So you should change the show more/less button to explicitly show or hide rows, depending on the state.

```
  $("#shower").on("click", function () {
      if ($("#shower").html() == "Show More") {
          $("#shower").attr("class", "btn btn-block btn-info");
          $("#shower").html("Show Less");
          $(".auto-collapse tr:gt(30)").show();
      } else {
          $("#shower").attr("class", "btn btn-block btn-primary");
          $("#shower").html("Show More");
          $(".auto-collapse tr:gt(30)").hide();
      }
  });
```